# Wait until playback has completed

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I'm using PortAudio as a front-end to a speech synthesis (Text to Speech) engine, and I want to provide a synchronous speak function that waits until playback has completed.

It seems like all of the PortAudio functions that deal with this only wait until the underlying API has finished consuming the audio data, not until playback has finished.

Is this possible with PortAudio? If not, are there any good cross-platform alternatives to PortAudio (has to include a C interface) that might support this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the streamFinished callback, as documented here:

http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#aa11e7b06b2cde8621551f5d527965838

is what you want. It may suffer from the same issue, but I think it would work.

Two other possibilities are:

- Use lower latency settings.
- Use the hardware timing. This information is available from calls like [GetStreamTime()](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#a2b3fb60e6949f37f7f134105ff425749). For example:

  - get the current time
  - push x seconds of audio to the hardware
  - wait for the hardware clock to show the start time plus x seconds

You might also be interested in this document:

http://www.rossbencina.com/static/writings/portaudio_sync_acmc2003.pdf

I'm afraid I don't know of another API with better support for this sort of thing.